# Error while installing OpenVZ kernel using yum in Fedora 17

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, openvz

I was trying to install OpenVZ kernel(rhel 6) in Fedora 17.Things worked fine until i issued the 'yum install vzkernel' command.The messages that i get at the end are:

1. ```
   Error: systemd conflict with vzkernel-2.6.32-042stab072.10.i686
   ```
2. ```
   Package: vzkernel-2.6.32-042stab072.10.i686(openvz-kernel-rhel6)
   Requires: /sbin/mkinitrd
   You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
   You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
   ```

Can't figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

openvz is not fully compatible with linux kernel >=3 yet.